# ¿De dónde proviene la expresión, errónea a mi parecer, "pedir cita previa"?

Tags: etimología, expresiones, modismos

**Nota**: Siguiendo la sugerencia de @Gorpik cambio la pregunta original: `Si pido una “Cita previa” significa que debo pedir una cita antes de la cita que me interesa?`, ya que he aceptado la respuesta de @Gustavson como la correcta.

En realidad esta es una pregunta trampa (*me refiero a la pregunta original*) para hablar de este caso, erróneo según creo, que se da, me parece, en todo el mundo hispánico.

Lo cierto es que es algo que me molesta desde la primera vez que lo vi: **Pedir cita previa**.

Creo que este mal uso se da por la abreviación del adverbio **previamente** en una posible frase original *Pedir cita **previamente***, pero esto lo convierte en adjetivo, por lo que modifica al nombre, por lo tanto, la frase pasa a decir una cosa totalmente distinta, yo creo, como dice en la pregunta, que implica que hay que pedir una cita anterior a la que realmente necesitamos....

¿A quién se le ocurrió...? no lo sé, pero bendito sea...  no podría haber salido con otra solución como:

- Es necesario tener cita
- Es preciso pedir cita
- Debe solicitar cita
- etc...

Comment: Más que del adverbio, que es una posibilidad, creo que en un principio pudo ser "previa cita": "Quienes quieran discutirlo, pueden venir, previa cita". Esto no es una respuesta, solo una conjetura.

Comment: La cuestión de fondo me parece interesante y he dado +1 a la pregunta por ello, pero, en general, es conveniente dejar más claro qué se pregunta. Podrías editar esto usando la idea que das en tu comentario a la respuesta aceptada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que la expresión redundante "cita previa" proviene del español culto, tal como indica [este artículo](https://www.milenio.com/cultura/cinco-frases-que-siempre-has-dicho-mal-y-quiza-no-lo-sabias). Transcribo lo que refiere:

> No hay citas que no sean previas, asegura Argüelles, pues el sustantivo femenino *cita* se refiere al "señalamiento, asignación de día, hora y lugar para verse y hablarse dos o más personas", o bien a la "reunión o encuentro entre dos o más personas, previamente acordado", según el Diccionario de la RAE.
>
> Por otro lado, el adjetivo previo, según María Moliner, "se aplica a lo que precede y sirve de preparación a algo".
>
> Esta expresión redundante tiene su origen en el español culto, puesto que es utilizada especialmente por profesionistas y hoy ha infestado incluso a las publicaciones impresas.

Comment: Gracias @Gustavson, obviamente tu respuesta no responde mi pregunta, pero aporta el dato de su origen, cosa por la cual habría sido mejor preguntar. Y me quedo con la parte que dice "...y hoy ha infestado incluso a las publicaciones escritas." Como dije antes, bendito el **culto profesionista** al que se le ocurrió.

Comment: Y por cierto, refuto a Argüellas, sólo si hay un mínimo de dos citas, entoces hay una cita previa y una posterior, si sólo hay una, entonces es cita, a secas.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que es mejor verlo como un pleonasmo, en el cual se usa la redundancia para resaltar, lo obvio, en el caso de los profesionistas como se menciona, cuantas veces no se tendrán que enfrentar al caso que van personas sin cita, a pesar de los énfasis y redundancias que le hace la persona para que la haga.